# redirect the vtiger application to jsp application when user click logout link in vtiger

Tags: php, jsp, redirect, vtiger, vtigercrm

I need to change the logout href into mysite jsp application url. where i get this line in vtiger folder .

I spent more than a hour not able to figure out can you please tell where should i get the file (view page source code).

```
<a target="" id="menubar_item_right_LBL_SIGN_OUT" href="?module=Users&amp;parent=Settings&amp;action=Logout">Sign Out</a>
```

**To example:**

```
<a target="" id="menubar_item_right_LBL_SIGN_OUT" href="http://192.168.1.X:8080/Admin/index.jsp">Sign Out</a>
```

why i need this mean because im redirecting jsp application to vtiger with sso lgoin that's no issue.so if user click logout i need redirect the user back to my jsp application  this is what i need exaclty.

Thanks advance.

Comment: please help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality by changing one line from below file: `root\modules\Users\actions\Logout.php`

Existing code: `header ('Location: index.php');`

Update code: `header ('Location: http://www.google.com/');` `//Enter your jsp application url`

Comment: Thank you. Cheers!

Comment: may i know vtiger developed using which framework ? @sAch